# Making a component invisible by accessing it from another mxml file in flex

Tags: apache-flex, components, panel, mxml, invisible

In my application i am having 2 mxml files **"Offerblock.mxml","messagblock.mxml"** which contains panels.
I am using a custom component (**panelMenuComponent.mxml**) which contains icons for showing in panel title bar.This custom  component is common for both mxml files.
Panels in **Offerblock.mxml** file need all 5 icons and panels in **messagblock.mxml** file need only 4 icons.
For both the mxml files i am using same skin for panel creation.In that skin only i am adding that **PanelMenuComponent** custom component.
So how to make 1 icon in custom component invisble while it was accessing from messageblock.mxml file.

Comment: I'm really confused as to what you're asking.   Perhaps sharing some code may help.  You make a lot of generic references to "mxml file" and I'm not sure which is which.  Generally, you can me a component invisible by setting the visible property to false.  I wrote this extended blog post about how two components can talk to each other: http://www.flextras.com/blog/index.cfm/2013/2/1/How-does-one-Flex-Component-talk-to-another-Flex-Component Does it help?

Comment: If I understand what you're asking, you have two components that are pretty much the same, but not entirely. Depending on the use case I would approach this a/ by creating one component with 2 states (one state where the fifth icon is visible and one where it's not) or b/ by creating one host component with 2 skins (this would be better suited if the visual appearance of the two states differs significantly).

Comment: we cant find your question

Answer (score 0):

As I do understand your question it would be - visible="false" as visible="true" is the default! If you want to get further into it use maybe modules and / or components! rgs aktell